# Java ArrayList of objects' add() method not working

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

Im new to JAVA, and Im facing a beginer's problem, I know :-P

**IN PLAIN ENGLISH => I'm trying to create an ArrayList of objects, and to add new objects in the array when required.**

OK, so here is a compact version of my code

```
package ACP.Employee;   //created package
import java.util.ArrayList;     //imported arraylist class
import ACP.Employee.EmployeeClass;  //imported employee class of same package

public class ClientClass
{
    ArrayList<EmployeeClass> empArray = new ArrayList<EmployeeClass>(); //created a new Array List

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int objcount = 0;   //variable to store objct count

        empArray.add(objcount, EmployeeClass obj);
    }
}
```

The IDE (Eclipse) gives me following errors on *empArray.add* line

- Cannot make a static reference to the non-static empArray
- EmployeeClass cannot be resolved to a variable
- Syntax error on token obj, delete this token.

I have also tried to replace that line with the following syntax,

```
empArray.add(new EmployeeClass());
```

**BUT** the following error remains.

- Cannot make a static reference to the non-static empArray

Kindly help out here, I have seen API Spec of ArrayList's add() method, which is following:::

> void add(int index, Object element) ==>> Inserts the specified element at the specified position index in the list 
>   boolean add(Object o) ==>> Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
>       SOURCE (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm)

Comment: Put a `static` in front of the declaration of the `empArray` variable. Like this: `static ArrayList<EmployeeClass> empArray = new ...`

Comment: empArray is a member of the class, main is an static member, so, this is forbidden

Comment: static method cannot access non-static member.

Comment: Ok it worked. Nice.! But I'm still confused about the concept here. Sorry guys, please don't be furious :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

1. You are trying to access a member of the class `ClientClass` from a static context (main). This is only possible if that member is static. Since `empArray` has no [modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) it will default to package-private which is not static. You will either have to make it accessible in a static context by declaring it static:

   `static ArrayList<EmployeeClass> empArray = new ArrayList<>();` 
    or create an instance of ClientClass and access its member

   ```
   ArrayList<EmployeeClass> empArray = new ArrayList<EmployeeClass>();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       ClientClass t = new ClientClass();
       t.empArray.add(new Employee());

   }
   ```
2. The way you are passing employees to the list to be added will not compile in java. Here is a [good tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) on how to create objects in java. In fact it seems you are new to Java, so I recommend you start on page one of the tutorials, they are very good for getting familiar with the language fast and you will be productive in no time.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. But as for 2nd point, compiler is compiling my code without any error. I also don't see any problem with my declaration, because in plain words, I'm creating ArrayList which is of type "EmployeeClass". Why shouldn't it? As I've read, ArrayList<T> => where T is template (can accommodate any data type).

Answer (score 2):

From `static` method you have access only to `static` fields.
From `not-static` method you have access to all fields.
E.g

```
private int i = 0;
private static int j = 0;

public void increment()
{
   i++; // correct
   j++; // correct
}
public static void staticIncrement()
{
   i++; // compilation error
   j++; // correct
}
```

So, in you example `empArray` should be `static`.

```
public class ClientClass
{
    static ArrayList<EmployeeClass> empArray = new ArrayList<EmployeeClass>(); 

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
       int objcount = 0;   //variable to store objct count

       empArray.add(objcount, new EmployeeClass());
       empArray.add(new EmployeeClass());
    }
}
```